# Android sqlite cursor query

Tags: java, android

I'm following the http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html tutorial. I am now trying to change the system so there is not just field 'comment' but rather field 'item' and 'price'.

Now that I have 2 Coloums rather then one the cursor seems to be causing the app to crash!
For example here is the code below:

```
        public List<Item> getAllItems() {
            List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ITEMS,
                    allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                Item item = cursorToItem(cursor);
                items.add(item);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            // Make sure to close the cursor
            cursor.close();
            return items;
        }

        private Item cursorToItem(Cursor cursor) {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
            item.setItem(cursor.getString(1));
            item.setPrice(cursor.getString(2));
            return item;
        }
```

LINE :

```
 Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ITEMS,
                    allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Is what is causing the error, I believe it has something to do with the fact that I have an additional column. can someone please tell me how to edit this line to get it to work, I have tried but don't understand this cursor query.

EDIT: By replacing allcolumns with null it ran. But now its crashing on:

```
public Item createItem(String item, String price) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ITEM, item);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PRICE, price);
        long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ITEMS, null,
                values);
        // To show how to query
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ITEMS,
                allColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursorToItem(cursor);
    }
```

on line:

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ITEMS,
                allColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
```

Here is the MySQLHelper.js:

```
package nupos.nupay.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String TABLE_ITEMS = "items";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_ITEM = "item";
public static final String COLUMN_PRICE = "price";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "items_test.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database creation sql statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_ITEMS + "( " + COLUMN_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_ITEM
        + " text not null," + COLUMN_PRICE
        +"  text not null);";

public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ITEMS);


    onCreate(db);
}

 }
```

Edit: The issue was the database was created initially without one of the fields.

Comment: please add the logcat error stacktrace

Comment: You have forgotten to put here declarations of the "database" and "MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ITEM"

Comment: Make sure that you removed the App with 1 column before running the code with 2 as the database is only updated not replace. You can take the DB file from the emulator and use sqlite.exe to make sure it is created correctly with all columns

Comment: you may have the wrong columns in `allColumns`.

Comment: try replacing **allColumns** with **null** in your query

Comment: allColumns is an array of String? try passing null instead of allColumns.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, `allColumns` doesn't sit with the `MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ITEMS` definition. Put here declarations and current values of all participying objects.

One more possibility - `database` object is not initialized properly and is null at the moment. You should check for such situations.